# Navigation hover background error

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with a `ul` list :

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">My Gifts</a>
        ...code... 
        <div class="add">
            <a href="#">add</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When I hover over "My gifts" link, it displays content after that. When I hover "My Gifts" I have image as background displaying behind "My gifts".

It sticks to "add" link too, how can I seperate or some how make that only "My gifts" link get the hover effect ?

Comment: please show your code in fiddle. Current description does not give too much clear idea

Comment: If you saw my original answer about the </div> tab, please ignore it, I missed your opening div tag!

Comment: Put your code here http://jsfiddle.net/ and tell us the exact problem your facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will just select the first a because its not wrapped within a div

```
li > a:hover {
     background-color: red;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css file you can add

```
.add a{
    background:transparent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want only **My Gifts** takes the hover effect try this:

```
<a href="#" class="hover-able">My Gifts</a>
```

Then add this CSS:

```
a.hover-able:hover {
    /* hover style here */
}
```

And don't add this class to other elements